# How would I go back to my original method after calling to another one from within?

Tags: java, arrays

I made a `getAverage` function, which traverses through an item array and adds the prices than finds the average. For my assignment problem I am suppose to ask if the user wishes to add more inputs into the array. I did this with an if statement than called the input method from inside the getAverage method.

How would I go back to the getAverage method to solve for the new average?

```
public static void input(Item[] arr) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double pricesAdded = 0;
    double average = 0;
    double numOfEntries = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
    {
        System.out.println("Enter item");
        String item = input.next();

        System.out.println("price");
        double price = input.nextDouble();

        if (price == -1) break;

        arr[i] = new Item(item, price);
        numOfEntries++;
    }


    for ( int i = 0; i < numOfEntries; i++)
        System.out.println(arr[i].toString());
}

public static double getAverage(Item[] itemArr) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double pricesAdded = 0;
    double average = 0;
    int numOfEntries = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < itemArr.length; i++) {
        if ( itemArr[i] == null) break;
        pricesAdded = pricesAdded + itemArr[i].getPrice();
        numOfEntries++;
    }
    System.out.println("Would you like to add more items");
    String userAnswer = input.next();
    if (userAnswer.equals("yes")) input(itemArr, numOfEntries);

    return average = pricesAdded / numOfEntries;
}
```

Comment: Why not ask them in the method which called `getAverage`?

Comment: I thought I was my calling the input method, but I see what you mean. So i put the for loop from the input method inside the getAverage method as well. That worked. Thank you!

Comment: Not really what I mean, `getInput` should just `getInput`, `getAverage` should return the average of the values it is passed, they really don't have anything to do with each other.  You should have another loop which calls `getInput` then calls `getAverage` based on the values returned from `getInput` and then which would ask the user if they want to input more values or not, the three process are separate

Comment: you need to be aware about the responsibility of each method.
`getAverage` method just to to be worried in calculate the average.
If you wanna increment your items list with more data, it's better to create another method to do that, like `addMoreItems` or something like that.
thus you make your logic cleaner and you will facilitate maintenance and debug ;)

Comment: @RodrigoGomes i need more than one vote on that comment to express how many unicorns it would take to show how much i agree with what you said.